# How to handle space within string in YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-resource-manager, cicd

I created YAML for CI/CD pipeline but the pipeline because of space in between the parameters name.

Here is the example of the parameters:

```
override parameters '
     -gbna-archive-trigger_properties_Kroger Manual File Archive_parameters_triggeringFile $(Funding_parameters_triggeringFile)
     -nesco_archive_trigger_properties_nesco Manual File Archive_parameters_triggeringFile $(Funding_parameters_triggeringFile)
     -gh-nesco-competitor-funding_properties_Competitor Funding_parameters_triggeringFile $(Funding_parameters_triggeringFile) '
```

Note: The template files are ARM templates but I am overriding the parameters in the YAML file.

Comment: Please describe your problem. What are you trying to do? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? Which part of your post is actual YAML content (please [format it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help))?

Comment: The [parameter names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#parameters) should be valid [JavaScript identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types) so shouldn't contain spaces.  The simplest solution would be to make the template compliant and remove the spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the parameter must be a valid JavaScript identifier. So your parameter name can't contain space. You can replace the space with _ or remove the space.
The document about parameter:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#parameters